# Ext JS: Combobox search error

Tags: javascript, search, extjs, combobox, store

I've a `combobox` which connects to DB with AJAX proxy. Questions are;

- When I type any string into `combobox`, it removes typed string when XHR loading ends..
- Secondly even if the searched record available inside request data, it's not displaying!

It's doing correct URL requst with `param`, typed input already exist in Dataset of XHR response but doesn't bring searched record on selection inside Dropdown list...

```
http://localhost:PORT/myapp/all/list?_dc=1522929831253&description=Sample&page=1&start=0&limit=1000
```

The thing is I've another `combobox` with same configuration and it works perfectly but this one is not!
How can I over come this situation? Here are some snippets of combobox;

Combobox:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.AccCombo',{
    extend:'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype:'samplecombo',
    requires: [],
    name: 'Sample Combo',
    fieldLabel: translations.comboDesc,
    displayField:'description',
    valueField:'sameid',

    store: {
        pageSize: 0,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            //idParam: 'sameid', // Thought idParam is not 'id' there can't be success and added this config but didnot effect
            url: MyApp.getUrl() + '/service/list',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        //autoSync: true,
        //remoteFilter: true
    },
    queryMode: 'remote',
    queryParam: 'description',
    autoLoad:true,
    bind: '{currRec.sameid}'
});
```

and here is sample JSON;

```
{
  "code": "XSAMPLE",
  "samid": 105899092,
  "description": "Sample Item",
},
```

Comment: where are you store.fields? fields:["samid","description"]. Unsure if this is the issue but regardless you need to define your store fields.

Comment: Switch `queryMode` from `remote` to `local`.

Comment: for `bind: '{currRec.sameid}'`, I think you should use `bind: {
                value: '{currRec.sameid}'
            }`

Comment: @stackato I've added model config to store but still behaves same...

Comment: @Tyr it works fine with `local` setting but couldn't understand why it's not bringing typed value for selection!? XHR request fetchs dataset and the record is already exict over there, even on `dropdown` but somehow  when it's `remote` instead of `local` can not select the record!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the issue is which totally all about my own enviroment setup has been solved.

Till now I thought that issue raises through Frontend request for filtering. Just couple hours ago has examine Backend if response for request as expected and has been figure out issue's reason *was not* Frontend!

The solution has solved through Backend with preparing required web service for query. **For this case Backend web service was not able to query with `description` field on URL** and they've added this service, problem solved...

FYI to all..